# Notify child component about changes in Angular2

Tags: events, angular

Suppose I have simple Angular2 component

```js
@Component({ selector: 'parent' })
@View({
    template: `
        <p>Parent {{ data }}</p>
        <child [model]="data"></child>
    `,
    directives : [Child]
})
export class Parent {
    data: number = 42;
}
```

as you can see it uses another simple component

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    properties : ['model']
})
@View({
    template: `
        <p>Child {{ model }}</p>
    `,
})
export class Child {
    model: number;
}
```

I am passing `model` from the `parent` component to the `child` through the angular's `[property]` syntax for data-binding. So if I want to track some changes of `model` in the `parent` I can easily add event to the `child` and through the `(event)` syntax track the changes in the 'parent'. So how can I implement the opposite situation when `parent` changes `model` and `child` want to be notified ?

Comment: if the parent changes the model, the child will receive the new value via the binding, so there is nothing special needed for the parent to send a new value to the child other than that

Comment: Yes, it will, and it is enough if I need just display data. But what if I need to add some additional logic for data change? Recalculate something or make http request and etc. This the case when $watch helps in angular 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your additional logic or calculations into [onChange](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/annotations/OnChange-interface.html) method, that is called after all of component's bound properties are updated.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    properties : ['model']
})
@View({
    template: `
        <p>Child {{ model }}</p>
    `,
})
class Child {
    model: number;

    onChange(map){
      if(map.model) {
        console.log('doing crazy stuff here');
        console.log(map.model); //SimpleChange {previousValue: 43, currentValue: 44}
      }
    }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vtUFS0uZ5I6oZQvEvA4s?p=preview)

Comment: In Angular 2.1.1 this no longer appears to work. Plunkr also seems broken.

Comment: In Angular 8, you can do the same with:

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['model']) {
        console.log('doing crazy stuff here');
        console.log(model);
    }
  }

Answer (score 10):

You can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) to manage it. For your example `Child` component must be looked like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  properties : ['model']
})
@View({
  template: `
    <p>Child {{ model }}</p>
  `,
})
class Child {
  _model: number;

  set model(newModelValue) {
    // Here we are
    console.log('new model value: ' + newModelValue)
    this._model = newModelValue;
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model;
  }
}
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOeRYYMea9wOg1WetXqu?p=preview) for your case

Comment: I like this solution. Do you think it will be common practice for such cases for angular2 ?

Comment: Well, if you just want to preprocess the `model` value I think the best choice is to use pipes.  `{{ model | pipe1 | pipe2 }}` - it's more concise and  declarative way. But maybe for some more complex situations getters/setters approach will be good.

Comment: alexpods, didn't you forget @Input()?