# Angular2 don't reflect edits to detail record until edits are saved

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a Parent component and a child component. The parent component is passing an object to the child via a property binding.

It is a simple scenario of Master-Child component communication

My requirement is to maintain the value in the parent object until the child component calls the save event after some manipulation of the data, at the same time update or overwrite the child data whenever a change happens in the parent object.

I have created a plunk with my experiments. It contains 3 components.

1. StudentDetails1 - The value is updated both ways.
2. StudentDetails2 - Implemented Setter and Getter for the property being bound, but the child data is not updated when the parent object changes.(Only works when being set from the parent constructor.)
   ([Notify child component about changes in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595070/notify-child-component-about-changes-in-angular2))
3. StudentDetails3 - Implemented ngOnChanges, but having the same issue as StudentDetails2

Can someone let me know the correct way to implement this in Angular2 using typescript? Or is the scenario absurd? :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/SQLRGjaapIslwHZYONY3?p=preview

```
//Parent component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

import {StudentDetails1} from './studentDetails1'
import {StudentDetails2} from './studentDetails2'
import {StudentDetails3} from './studentDetails3'
import {Student} from './student'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <h2>Student Master</h2>
    Selected Student <input [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent.name" type="text">
    <student-details1 [student]="selectedStudent" (onCompletion)="onCompletion($event)"></student-details1>
    <student-details2 [student]="selectedStudent" (onCompletion)="onCompletion($event)"></student-details2>
    <student-details3 [student]="selectedStudent" (onCompletion)="onCompletion($event)"></student-details3>
  `,
  directives: [StudentDetails1,StudentDetails2,StudentDetails3]
})
export class App {
  public title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  public selectedStudent: Student;

  constructor() {
      this.selectedStudent = {
          id: 1,
          name: "John Doe"
      }
  }

  onCompletion(modifiedStudent: Student) {
      this.selectedStudent = modifiedStudent;
  }
}
```

Child1

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
import {Student} from './student'
@Component({
  selector: 'student-details1',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <h3>Student Details 1</h3>
    Student : <input [(ngModel)]="student.name" type="text">
    <a href="javascript:;" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</a>
  `,
  directives: [],
  inputs:["student"],
  outputs: ['onCompletion']
})
export class StudentDetails1 {
  onCompletion: EventEmitter<Student> = new EventEmitter();

  public student:Student;

  onSubmit(){
      this.student.name += "_Modified";
      this.onCompletion.emit(this.student);
  }
}
```

Child2

```
import {Component,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'
import {Student} from './student'
@Component({
  selector: 'student-details2',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <h3>Student Details 2</h3>
    Student : <input [(ngModel)]="_student.name" type="text">
    <a href="javascript:;" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</a>
  `,
  directives: [],
  inputs:["student"],
  outputs: ['onCompletion']
})
export class StudentDetails2 {
  onCompletion: EventEmitter<Student> = new EventEmitter();

  private _student:Student;
  set student(value:Student){
    this._student = {
      id:value.id,
      name:value.name
    }
  }
  get student(){
    return _student;
  }

  onSubmit(){
      this._student.name += "_Modified";
      this.onCompletion.emit(this._student);
  }
}
```

Child3

```
import {Component,EventEmitter,OnChanges} from 'angular2/core'
import {Student} from './student'
@Component({
  selector: 'student-details3',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <h3>Student Details 3</h3>
    Student : <input [(ngModel)]="_student.name" type="text">
    <a href="javascript:;" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</a>
  `,
  directives: [],
  inputs:["student"],
  outputs: ['onCompletion']
})
export class StudentDetails3 implements OnChanges {
  onCompletion: EventEmitter<Student> = new EventEmitter();

  private _student:Student;
  public student:Student;

  onSubmit(){
      this._student.name += "_Modified";
      this.onCompletion.emit(this._student);
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    this._student = {
      id:this.student.id,
      name:this.student.name
    }
  }
}
```

Ram

Comment: That's a lot of information but it's not entirely clear to me what you actually want to know.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you pls try running the plunk? I need the parent data to be updated only when the Save is clicked by the child component. At the same time, the data should be passed to the child component as and when the parent object is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way

http://plnkr.co/edit/bOyWbU3bznFYfUFpGYOM?p=preview (src/studentDetails1.ts)

Split downstream- and upstream-binding

```
Student : <input [ngModel]="student.name" (ngModelChange)="_student=$event" type="text">
```

```
export class StudentDetails1 {
  onCompletion: EventEmitter<Student> = new EventEmitter();

  public student:Student;
  private _student:Student;

  onSubmit(){
      // update upstream model only on submit
      this.student.name = this._student + "_Modified";
      this.onCompletion.emit(this.student);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, what you just did was intersecting the DOM -> Component change and assigning it to a private object. Is this the usual way to tackle this scenario?

Comment: It depends on what other requirements you have. You can also copy the value from the `@Input() student:Student;` in `ngOnInit()` to `this._student`, bind to `[(ngModel)]="_student"` and then on submit update upstream like demonstrated. There are always many ways to achieve something. What I demonstrated seemed the simplest for the task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

A generic (elegant) solution to the "edit a detail record" problem is presented in the [Hierarchical Injectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) dev guide.

A generic `EditItem<T>` class and a generic `RestoreService<T>` service are used to facilitate editing a detail record.  Changes are not reflected to the parent (i.e., the rest of the application) unless the user saves the changes.

Comment: Just reached till the (5. Forms) developer guide, when I ran into this doubt. A long long way to go. This was exactly the scenario I was thinking of. Since this is a very common scenario in any app, shouldn't this be somehow be a built-in feature of Angular2 rather than everyone implementing the same generic class and going through the trouble of tracking the state of the item? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: @rmchndrng, well, one reason for not including it: you might want to add more features to one or both of the generic classes.  And one could argue that this type of functionality it is outside the scope of what a framework should provide.  And I believe generics are a TypeScript feature (not ES2015).