# Angular2 - notify child that parent object changed so child can refire an ngIf inside its template

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I have a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595070/notify-child-component-about-changes-in-angular2), but it seems that question is out of date as neither of the 2 answers work for me.

The child component is simply rendering data from a complex object called `Proposal` passed as an input (it has no user controls at all, so does not need to fire any events or pass anything out).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fb-proposal-document',
  templateUrl: './proposal-document.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./proposal-document.component.css']
})
export class ProposalDocumentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() proposal: Proposal;

  constructor()
}
```

The pertinent part of the template is this, iterating an array and checking a property to display different text using `*ngIf`:

```
<li class="section" *ngFor="let qp of proposal?.quoted_products">
  <li class="section" *ngFor="let room of qp?.rooms">
    ...
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        Supply
        <span *ngIf="room.is_fitted">
          and install
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="!room.is_fitted">
          only
        </span>                    
      </div>
    </div>
    ...                
  </li>
</li>
```

In the parent, the user can click a checkbox to change 'is_fitted' to true or false. The parent is using a domain-drive form. In the `ngOnInit` of the parent is this code:

```
this.myForm.controls['isFitted'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => {
    this.proposal.is_fitted = value;
    let qp = this.proposal.quoted_products[this.qpCurrentIndex];
      qp.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
        room.is_fitted = value;
    });
  }
);
```

which correctly updates the property. I can see that if I `console.log` it. So the question is, how can I get the child to refire/re-process the `*ngIf` when the embedded `room.is_fitted` values change?

I have tried implementing [this idea](https://hahoangv.wordpress.com/2016/05/22/angular-2-essentials-understanding-the-viewchild/), using ViewChild, so the above code in ngOnInit then becomes:

```
this.myForm.controls['isFitted'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => {
    this.proposal.is_fitted = value;
    let qp = this.proposal.quoted_products[this.qpCurrentIndex];
      qp.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
        room.is_fitted = value;
    });
    this.proposalDocument.notifyChange(this.proposal);
  }
);
```

but that does not work either. My notifyChange in the child is called successfully:

```
  notifyChange(proposal: Proposal) {
    console.log('I changed');
    this.proposal = proposal;
  }
```

but the view does not update - the `*ngIf` logic does not get reprocessed.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11704#issuecomment-247936812

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the useful link, except what is not explained (neither in the Angular Docs LifeCycle Hooks section) is how you force the ngIf to reprocess the object and cause the view to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took out all the code and wrote it again from scratch and my very fist attempt now works:

```
this.myForm.controls['isFitted'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => {
    this.proposal.is_fitted = value;
    let qp = this.proposal.quoted_products[this.qpCurrentIndex];
      qp.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
        room.is_fitted = value;
    });
  }
);
```

I don't need to notify the child at all. The view updates automatically.

I was convinced from everything I have read that complex objects do not update deep properties - only if you change the reference to the object itself. But here I am now changing deep properties and I am not notifying the child by calling ngOnChanges, and it works. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

See my other answer, because this all seems unnecessary now. But I'll leave here it here as it may help someone.

---

Following the link provided by @JBNizet in the comments on the question, I tried this solution:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log('I changed ngOnChanges');
    console.log(changes);
    for (let propName in changes){
      if (propName == 'is_fitted') {
        this.proposal.quoted_products.forEach(function(qp) {
          qp.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
            room.is_fitted = changes[propName].currentValue;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  };
```

So instead of calling my custom notifyChange, the parent is calling this ngOnChanges method, like this:

```
this.myForm.controls['isFitted'].valueChanges.subscribe(
  value => {
    this.proposal.is_fitted = value;
    this.proposalDocument.ngOnChanges({
        is_fitted: value 
    });
  }
);
```

The new value arrives in the child, I can see it logged in the console, the property is updated on the model and the view is **NOW** updated.

I do wonder if this is efficient, and whether I should detach and reattach before and after this double loop, like so:

```
for (let propName in changes){
  if (propName == 'is_fitted') {
    console.log('detaching');
    this.ref.detach();
    this.proposal.quoted_products.forEach(function(qp) {
      qp.rooms.forEach(function(room) {
        room.is_fitted = changes[propName].currentValue;
      });
    });
    this.ref.reattach();
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
};
```

More info on `detectChanges()` in [this official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detach).